# Возможно ли вывести точное соответствие в SQL первым результатом?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Я использую запрос `SELECT * FROM "words" WHERE "word" LIKE "%ロシア%"` и получаю результат:

[image: Результат моего запроса]

Но мне нужно, чтобы первым результатом был "ロシア" и уже потом остальные. Возможно ли этого добиться?

Comment: `ORDER BY word`?

Comment: Попробуйте `ORDER BY word`, только обратите внимание, что у вас `LIKE '%...'`, это (% wildcard) значит, что могут быть любое количество символов до искомой комбинации и что-то другое может пролезть ранее.

Comment: ORDER BY (word != "%ロシア%") если mysql такое понимает